# Rails 3: Heroku Herogit Plugin

Tags: rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I don't quite understand how to setup the herogit plugin recommended in the Heroku newsletter (https://github.com/jbarnette/herogit).

When I do `$heroku config` inside my app I already have the config info.

I also don't understand how to deploy on both apps using `git push` and `heroku rake db:migrate`.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like your asking about checking into GitHub separately from checking stuff into Heroku?

Comment: I'm trying to create a staging server for my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Herogit let's you store your Heroku credentials in your git repo so if you have apps which use different credentials, eg different clients then this makes it easier. If you're just dealing with the one app then there's not much point using it.

I wrote a blog post on managing multiple environments on my blog http://john.beynon.org.uk/developing-with-multiple-environments-on-hero